# Internet Explorer Driver use in Java

Tags: java, internet-explorer, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

I am using Selenium Webdriver with Java. I would like check to operation of IEdriver. The following code works fine while opening Firefox or Chrome. I want the script to work for Internet Explorer as well.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "C:\\IEDriverServer.exe");
WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
driver.get("www.google.com");
driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys("abc");
driver.close();
```

I get the following error:

> Unable to find element with name == q (WARNING: The server did not
>   provide any stacktrace information)

I got the same phenomenon, when i use xpath or id in findElement method. How can I solve this problem in Selenium WebDriver with Java? Will be grateful for any help.

Comment: Does it open your webpage (www.google.com) and give this error or does it throw the error even before opening it?

Comment: Opens the website, but had not found the webelement.

Comment: Please try [Maximizing your window](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10247860/4193730) and giving an [implicit wait of 10 seconds](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#implicit-waits) and check

Comment: Have you set the Protected Settings of each mode to same value ? [This is a must for IE-7 and higher](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver#Required_Configuration)

Comment: @Subh Sure, i use this:
  `DesiredCapabilities ieCapabilities = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();  
  ieCapabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS, true);
  WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(ieCapabilities);`

Comment: @Milky : Oh! Although using ["INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGN‌​ORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS"risks the stability of the code](http://jimevansmusic.blogspot.in/2012/08/youre-doing-it-wrong-protected-mode-and.html), but this should work. Can you please tell me which version of IE , Selenium-bindings, and IEDriverServer.exe, are you using ? I used IE-10 with Selenium 2.45.0 and IEDriverServer.exe version 2.44.0.0 ; it is working fine at my end.

Comment: @Subh Selenium version 2.47.1, IE version 10, IEDriverServer version 2.47.0.0

Comment: Okay. I tried with your configurations with [IEDriverServer.exe of 32-bit Windows IE](http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/2.47/IEDriverServer_Win32_2.47.0.zip) and it worked. **[64-bit executable is a bit problematic for IE-10/11](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/893)**. Can you please let me know if you have tried with a 64-bit IE exe or a 32-bit one ?

Comment: @Subh I have 64-bit OS.

Comment: That's fine. I am talking about the IEDriverServer.exe version. Are you using the 32-bit one or 64-bit ?

Comment: I'm using the 32-bit IEDriverServer.exe. If I use the 64-bit version of the driver, then it does not open the webpage.

Comment: Oh! There goes the last arrow in my quiver.. Sorry, I won't be of any further help. :( Hope someone helps you out here.